# Can't remember my passcode

Tags: itunes, iphone, restore, find-my-iphone, security

I can't remember my passcode and I have Find my phone app turned on my phone is disabled and says connect to itunes but it wont let me restart my phone as i have find my phone app turned on i have deleted my find my phone account in hope it would fix it but it didnt and  now i cant get it working at all what should I do? :( and it also wont let me connect to the wifi or data as it is disabled.(IPhone 4s)

Answer (score 3):

You should put your device into DFU Mode.
Here are the steps:

Plug your device into the computer

Press and hold both the power and home buttons until the screen goes black then release the power button still holding down the home button.

The screen should stay black and your device should popup in iTunes saying it needs to be restored.

Click restore and confirm any prompts that popup.

Let iTunes restore your device and do not unplug your device.

Once you're finished it should take you to setup and when activating enter your iCloud details when asked.

Comment: If you felt that this helped you please mark your question as solved by clicking the check next to my answer as it helps me develop and I would really appreciate it! :)